# Reference another property of the same PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I have a `PSCustomObject` declared and it has multiple members. Some of them need to reference each other. E.g.

```
$data = [PSCustomObject]@{
    a = "x"
    b = "y"
    c = "z"
    d = "$a - $b - $c"
}
```

What I would expect is `$data.d` to return:

```
x - y - z
```

I've tried referencing the other properties by:

- `$a`
- `$this.a`
- `$_.a`
- `$data.a`

But none of these seem to work and the output of `$data.d` is:

```
 -  -
```

**Note:** if we run the script for the second time `$data.a` might reference the `$data` variable from the previous run, so we need to make sure that the variables are cleaned before running.

Comment: a,b,c have never been variables, the properties created inside the pscustomobject are available ***after*** creation as properties not variables. Nonexistent variables resolve to nothing/$null.

Answer (score 3):

I quess you actually looking for a [`ScriptProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-6):

```
$data = [PSCustomObject]@{
    a = "x"
    b = "y"
    c = "z"
}

$data | Add-Member ScriptProperty d {"$($this.a) - $($this.b) - $($this.c)"}

$data

a b c d
- - - -
x y z x - y - z
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use a `class`

```
class MyData {
    $a 
    $b
    $c
    $d = "$a + $b + $c"

    MyData ($a, $b, $c) 
    {
        $this.a = $a
        $this.b = $b
        $this.c = $c
    }
}
$data = [MyData]::new('x','y','z')
$data.d
```

returns

```
x + y + z
```